# Pandas linear interpolation for geometrical X-Y data seems to ignore points

Tags: python, pandas, linear-interpolation, pandas-resample

I am trying to upsample my dataframe in pandas (from 50 Hz to 2500 Hz). I have to upsample to match a sensor that was sampled at this higher frequency. I have points in x, y, z coming from a milling machine.
When I am plotting the original data the lines look straight, as I would expect.

[image: Original data]
[image: Original data zoomed in]

I am interpolating the dataframe like this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='time', inplace=True)
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
upsampled = new_df.resample('0.4ms').interpolate(method='linear')
plt.scatter(upsampled['X[mm]'], upsampled['Y[mm]'], s=0.5)
plt.plot()
```

I also tried with

```
upsampled = df.resample('0.4L').interpolate(method='linear')
```

I expect the new points to always come between the original points. Since I am going from 50 Hz to 2500 Hz, I expect 50 points uniformly spaced between each pair of points in the original data. However, it seems that some of the original points are ignored, as can be seen in the picture below (the second picture is zoomed in on a particularly troublesome spot).

[image: Upsample data superimposed]
[image: Upsample data superimposed and zoomed]

This figure shows the original points in orange and the upsampled, interpolated points in blue (both are scattered, although the upsampled points are so dense it appears as a plot). The code for this is shown below.

```
upsampled = df.resample('0.4ms').interpolate(method='linear')
plt.scatter(upsampled['X[mm]'], upsampled['Y[mm]'], s=0.5, c='blue') 
plt.scatter(df['X[mm]'], df['Y[mm]'], s=0.5, c='orange')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
fig.show()
```

Any ideas how I could make the interpolation work?

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work as expected? What was the expected result for interpolation?

Comment: Please keep it in english!

Comment: @Lore Sorry guys for the pictures, it was my first question here

Comment: @perl I expected the result of the interpolation to be more similar to the first picture. In the third picture points that were in the original dataframe are no longer there and the lines are not straight.

Comment: @FedericaTomola Can you share some sample data, so that it's possible to check what is happening?

Comment: @perl I have updated the question with more information about the problem

Comment: OK, posted what I think should be the problem and what I think should fix it

Comment: @Federica no problem, hope you'll be well, ciao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the timestamps in the original and resampled DataFrames are not aligned, so when resampling we need to specify how to deal with that.

Since the original is at 50 Hz and the resampled is at 2500 Hz, simply taking `mean` should fix it:

```
upsampled = new_df.resample('0.4ms').mean().interpolate(method='linear')
```

Unfortunately, without having any sample data, I cannot verify that it works. Please let me know if it does help

Comment: thank you so much, this works! 
Though, in my original dataframe I also have two columns with strings (test number, and delta time) which have now disappeared. Could I apply the mean just to the column with the timestamp?

Comment: @FedericaTomola You can do `first` instead of `mean`: `new_df.resample('0.4ms').first().interpolate()`. This will keep the string values (without interpolation, of course)

Comment: @FedericaTomola Great, then can you please mark the answer as accepted?